# Changing pad shape/size selectively on an inner layer in Eagle

Tags: eaglecad, layout

I'm trying to create a plated cutout in eagle for a DC barrel jack connector (https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Prototyping/Barrel-Connector-PJ-202A.pdf) for a 4 layer board to be fabed by oshpark.  I've followed the general guidelines provided by eagle:

In the package I used a long pad with a drill size equal to the shortest dimension of the desired rectangle.  I then drew a rectangle of the desired cut out on the middle layers and milling layer.

The trouble is that oshpark doesn't use the milling layer -- they want all holes on the dimension layer so I am forced to copy the rectangle onto the dimension layer too.  The DRC for oshpark also dictates a 15 mil spacing between copper and dimension.  What this means is that I'm left with a pad that's unconnected on the inner layers because the dimension layer +15 mil spacing is too far away from the pad on the inner layer.

[image]

Obviously it would be nice to have that connected.  I played with the restring of pads and can of course increase that so there's contact as shown here:

[image]

The problem is that now every pad now has this property, which isn't desirable.  Is there anyway to either change the shape of inner layer pads selectively or selectively change the restring value for a package?  Alternatively is there anyway to accomplish what I'm trying to do in another way?

Comment: Why don't you generate the gerbers instead of sending off design files?  That way you can do things in whichever layer(s) suits you.

Comment: Interesting.  And then edit the gerbers?  As it stands if I generate the gerbers the gerbers will reflect the design as is.

Comment: You use another layer that does not interfere with your routing (like the milling layer).  Then you generate that particular gerber from both dimension and milling layers.  No need to edit the gerbers.

Comment: If you post as an answer I'm happy to give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending off the design files, generate the gerbers yourself (which is what most pcb manufacturers accept anyway).

Use layers that do not interfere with your routing (like the milling layer), and generate that particular gerber file using both the dimension and the milling layer.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshots it appears you have created an internal cut-out (I think). Therefore you won't be able to do what you want with OSHPark. On their [support website](http://support.oshpark.com/support/articles/134889-internal-cutouts-and-slots) it states that they do not support **plated** cut-outs:

> All internal cutouts will be unplated, and must be 0.1 inches (2.54mm / 100 mil) wide.

The link above is worth a look as it suggests some work-arounds.

When I include these types of jack connectors in my EAGLE projects, I use plated through holes for the legs which are quite a bit bigger than the actual legs - as shown in the picture towards the end of the page linked above.

Also, in addition to *apalopohapa*'s answer (I do not have enough rep to comment on his answer), OSHPark provide the CAM job file for generating your own gerber files; refer to this page: http://support.oshpark.com/support/solutions/articles/106997-cam-job-for-eagle-cad

Comment: Yeah that's what the site says, but when I emailed them they said it would work.  I've actually spun a board with an HDMI connector (similar situation), but didn't have a need to connect the shell of the connector and they came back as intended.  I've also done the large plated through hole, but it's just really clunky and takes up a lot of board space. I know that oshpark can process the .brd, but if you have large polygons etc their server crashes and tosses the job.  My board is ~4"x4" with polygons on all 4 layers -- the oshpark processing engine breaks every time I try to upload it.

Comment: BTW another reason I like generating my own gerbers is that I can use whatever font I want in eagle whereas if I use the oshpark gerber generators then I'm limited to vector font.

Comment: That's interesting, didn't know that they would actually allow it. Have never encountered the large polygon issue with their website before though, have always just uploaded a Gerbers ZIP. The CAM job in the link above makes that very straightforward (although you might want to turn on additional layers in the top and bottom silkscreen menus).